# A view where a user doesn't have a certain content type

Tags: views

I am trying to create a view where a user doest have a certain content type.

Say for instance I have content types A, B and C and I only want to return results to show users who don’t have content type A but could have B or C.

I have created a view for (users) and linked it to the content authored. I have played about a bit but haven’t managed to find the correct filters. Can anyone help??

Many thanks

David

Comment: I am trying to create a list of users who don’t have content type A. not sure either of these answers sound like they would do the trick?

Comment: It is not clear, what you want. Can you explain it better.

Comment: I am setting up a review website. I have a content type called “Review”.I also have other content types called Hotel’s, Restaurants etc. The content type “Reviews” can reference all the other content types thus reviewing them.

Comment: When a review is left, other users can vote on the review.A user is given a rating based on his average score (of votes) across all the reviews they have left.This might help visually http://yourreviews.com/reviewerrating. I want to give a beginners status to users who have not left any reviews. A user could have other content types though, i.e. they could have created a Hotel but not ended up reviewing it so the view must specifically show users who have not created any content types of “Review”.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure what you need to do is set in the access permissions of the view to be permission: Publish Content

Answer (score 0):

You could add all content types. If the user doesn't have that content type, they will not see output anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of the following ways.

1. Implement `hook_views_query_alter()` and alter the query to add the where clause.
2. Or, Install `Flag` module

   - Create a user flag called `Reviewer`
   - Create a rule

     - Add a event : Content type `Review` is saved.
     - Condition : User is not flagged
     - Action : Flag the user
   - Now create your view and add relationship with `Flags` and add a filter `User is not flagged`
3. Similar to step 2, but instead of flag assign a new role, reviewer, and in your view add a filter to check user does not have that role.

Comment: Being self taught in the last few months I think step 1 is beyond me however I can manage the flag module combined with rules which I’m already using on the site so I think I would look at that. 

Many thanks